# Filter based on checkbox clicked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to filter the product based on user clicked checkbox. I want to append the checkbox value and show it in URL and filter products based on those value in URL. I used `onChange="this.form.submit()"` but everytime i check the checkbox it replaces old value with new in URL. How to append all these values and filter based on those values.

```
<form action="{{route('filter')}}" method="GET"
>  

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">


         <div class="col-md-4">
            Search
        <input type="checkbox" name="category_id['samsung']" class="form-control" value="1" onChange="this.form.submit(){{ request()->filled('category_id.samsung') ? 'checked' :''}}">Samsung

        <input type="checkbox" name="category_id['android']" class="form-control" value="2"onChange="this.form.submit(){{ request()->filled('category_id.android') ? 'checked' :''}}" >Android

        <input type="checkbox" name="category_id['apple']" class="form-control" value="3" onChange="this.form.submit(){{ request()->filled('category_id.apple') ? 'checked' :''}}">Apple
        </div>
    </form>
```

my url is browser is:

```
http://localhost:8000/?category_id%5B%27samsung%27%5D=1

http://localhost:8000/?category_id%5B%27android%27%5D=2

http://localhost:8000/?category_id%5B%27apple%27%5D=3
```

the value is url is updated when i checked another checkbox, actually i need to append it

Comment: AJAX would be a better option in this scenario.

Comment: Yup, I think AJAX is the best choice

Comment: Use `category_id[]` for name instead of `category_id['apple']`

Comment: yes did, no any changes

Comment: i want use only laravel

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in the comments, use `category_id[]` as the name attribute for each input. Then the URL becomes `http://localhost:8000/?category_id[]=1`.

The problem remains that on every page load the checkboxes are cleared. Pre-selecting them can be done with these conditions:

```
is_array(request()->input('category_id')) && 
in_array('1', request()->input('category_id')) ? 'checked' : ''
```

Now it is possible to filter on multiple items, and the URL becomes like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/?category_id[]=1&category_id[]=2
```

Here is a full solution:

```
<form action="{{ route('filter') }}" method="GET">  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Search
                <input type="checkbox" name="category_id[]" class="form-control" value="1" onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ is_array(request()->input('category_id')) && in_array('1', request()->input('category_id')) ? 'checked' : ''}}>Samsung
                <input type="checkbox" name="category_id[]" class="form-control" value="2" onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ is_array(request()->input('category_id')) && in_array('2', request()->input('category_id')) ? 'checked' : ''}}>Android
                <input type="checkbox" name="category_id[]" class="form-control" value="3" onChange="this.form.submit()" {{ is_array(request()->input('category_id')) && in_array('3', request()->input('category_id')) ? 'checked' : ''}}>Apple
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```